# jQuery removeProp is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to remove all style properties. When I add the style via `.css({cursor:"not-allowed"})` the element would look like this:

```
<div id="id" style="cursor:not-allowed;">
  My Text
</div>
```

I know I could set `.css({"cursor"=""})` but I don't want to set every single style attribute to `""`. I don't get why `.removeProp("style")` is not working. Isn't it supposed to do exactly that?

```js
function applyStyle() {
  $("#id").css({ cursor: "not-allowed" });
}

function removeStyle() {
  $("#id").removeProp("style");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id">
  My Text
</div>
<button onclick="applyStyle()">Apply style</button>
<button onclick="removeStyle()">Remove style</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/), as `style` is an attribute

```js
function applyStyle() {
  $("#id").css({ cursor: "not-allowed" });
}

function removeStyle() {
  $("#id").removeAttr("style");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id">
  My Text
</div>
<button onclick="applyStyle()">Apply style</button>
<button onclick="removeStyle()">Remove style</button>
```